# Distributing uneven data evenly scaling closely data distantly

Tags: statistics

I have data point which are too close, I am using `linear scale` to plot my points. But `linear scale` `range` values are close too and point are over lapping and `clustering`, is there any other scale or method which map close data distantly.

Close data mean data like this `[1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4....]`

Comment: what is the max value? and maybe elaborate a bit more what you like to achieve?

Comment: the problem is I am plotting a graph using `linear`  scale, my domain i.e data points are too close, so do there range or the value `linear` scales return so I am looking for `scale` or `technique` to spread my range